# PostgreSQL 13.6 - Querying JSON resulting in "operator does not exist: json -> record"

Tags: json, postgresql

I have `json` column inside my PostgreSQL table that looks something similar to this:

```
{"example--4--":"test 1","another example--6--":"test 2","final example--e35b172a-af71-4207-91be-d1dc357fe8f3--Equipment":"ticked"}

{"example--4--":"test 4","another example--6--":"test 5","final example--e35b172a-af71-4207-91be-d1dc357fe8f3--Equipment":"ticked"}
```

Each key contains a map which is separated by `--`. The prefix is unique, ie: "example", "another example" and "final example".

I need to query on the unique prefix and so far, nothing I'm trying is even close.

```
select some_table.json_column from some_table
left join lateral (select array(select * from json_object_keys(some_table.json_column) as keys) k on true
where (select SPLIT_PART(k::text, '--', 1) as part_name) = 'example'
and some_table.json_column->>k = 'test 1'
```

The above is resulting in the following error (last line):

> operator does not exist: json -> record

My expected output would be any records where `"example--4--":"test 1"` is present (in my above example, the only result would be)

```
{"example--4--":"test 1","another example--6--":"test 2","final example--e35b172a-af71-4207-91be-d1dc357fe8f3--Equipment":"ticked"}
```

Any help appreciated. After debugging around for a while, I can see the main issue resolves in the implicit cast to `::text`. `k` seems to be a "record" of the keys that I need to loop and split to compare, currently, I'm casting a record to text which is causing the issue.

Comment: "*My expected output would be any records where "example--4--":"test 1"* is present"  looks like a simple `where the_column ? 'example--4--'`

Comment: You'd think, but I only know the first part, ie `example`, I need to then find the full key `example--4--` to then check the value is `test 1` or whatever @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is to use an EXIST condition together with `jsonb_each_text()`

```
select *
from the_table
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each_text(data) as x(key,value)
              where x.key like 'example%'
                and x.value = 'test 1')
```

If your column isn't a `jsonb` (which it should be), you need to use `json_each_text()` instead

Another option is to use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where data @? '$.keyvalue() ? (@.key like_regex  "^example" && @.value == "test 1")'
```

Comment: I really didn't think this straight forwards, thank-you! Really appreciate the explanation.